# Is the product manifold $S^{1} \times \text{Bryant soliton on } R^{n-1}$ is non-collapsed?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, geometric-topology, ricci-flow

I am puzzed that whether the product manifold $S^{1} \times \text{Bryant soliton on } R^{n-1}$ is non-collapsed, as my understanding of the definition non-collapsed and computation, I believe it is ture, Right?